# Explicitly linked Solidity libraries produce bigger contract size than having it embedded

Tags: solidity, evm, library, visibility, blockchain-size

If I replace all the library functions' visibility to either `external` or `public`, I will have to deploy the libraries separately first, and then explicitly link them in the contract which is using them. When I do that, the contract size becomes bigger, instead of smaller. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm assuming this is because the library I am using includes some functions with some params which have `storage` data location?